# How to prove $\text{det}(I+xy^{\top}+wz^{\top})=(1+y^{\top}x)(1+z^{\top}w)-(x^{\top}z)(y^{\top}w)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose $x,y,z,w$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Show that $\text{det}(I+xy^{\top}+wz^{\top})=(1+y^{\top}x)(1+z^{\top}w)-(x^{\top}z)(y^{\top}w)$.

Comment: Any attempts so far? Do you know any potentially useful theorems? For example, things like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman–Morrison_formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the matrix 
$$\tag1
\begin{bmatrix} 1+y^Tx & y^Tw \\ z^Tx & 1+z^Tw \end{bmatrix} 
=I + \begin{bmatrix} y^T\\ z^T \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  x & w\end{bmatrix}
$$
For any $A,B$, we have the equality $\det(I+AB)=\det(I+BA)$. So the determinant in $(1)$ is equal to the determinant of 
$$
I + \begin{bmatrix}  x & w\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y^T\\ z^T \end{bmatrix} 
=I+xy^T+wz^T. 
$$

---

**Proof of the equality** $\det(I+AB)=\det(I+BA)$.

The matrices $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues (padding with zeroes when the sizes are not equal). So $I+AB$ and $I+BA$ have the same eigenvalues, and if the two lists have different length then the remaining eigenvalues are $1$. As the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, we get $\det(I+AB)=\det(I+BA)$.